# Sharing a network drive over WAN with MacOS and Linux

Tags: linux, macos, sshfs, network-drive

I would like to share a network drive in a way that can be accessed from both MacOS and Linux, over the internet. I have a home Linux server, as well as one on AWS. The MacOS computer will be another person's, who is not as technically versed. I'd prefer to keep things on their end simple.

In the past, I have been able to share drives between a home server and Linux laptops by using SSHFS. It worked well, but it seems that SSHFS would require some setup to work on MacOS. Are there any other options that I can consider?

Most of the files shared would be either documents or images.

Comment: I'd recommend Dropbox, Google Drive, or similar. You'll have 'great fun' trying to get a novice to set up a structure that could safely punch a hole in their firewall to reach a specific folder on a specific computer & also not mess up the rest of their network. [& that's before you even consider their IP will be either dynamic or possibly CGNAT.] Setting up the Mac sharing is the easy bit.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I had it the wrong way round in my head - *you* would have to do the hole-punching. All they would need would be the reliable method to track your IP address, be able to run a command line clietnt… the answer is still 'use dropbox' etc.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you're already having a server and the person on the other hand is not technically engaged in the needed depth: Maybe you're interested in hosting your own cloud for private use. That way the data is under your control at any given point in time, you can manage access/features very easily

Nexcloud offers a free on-premise (self-hosted) alternative to dropbox/onedrive/... - Maybe that's of interest. -> There are other companies offering similar software as well, but nextcloud worked best for me in the past, which is why i suggest this one.

Of course you can set up a network-share or something similar, but the settings required as well as the knowledge needed may just be out of hand in this case, which is why my answer incorporates an easy self-managed solution that hopefully fits your needs (if you pursue it).